# Ubuntu on BQ aquaris. Features

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq, aquaris

I am thinking about buying the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition. I've been making some research on the Internet about the phone and I am worried about the software support Ubuntu for phones currently has.

I saw some people complaining about the software support: I have no issues about having to compile a non-official whatsapp version for the mobile phone, but what about Google Drive, Google hangout and so on?

Is there any software (official or not) that supports these Google systems?

I am particulary interested in these programs/services:

1. Drive
2. Hangouts
3. Whatsapp: I found this webpage so there seems to be a solution for Whatsapp
   http://www.whatsappfor.org/software/whatsapp-ubuntu-phone-touch/

Any comments based on the BQ Aquaris Ubuntu owners/users experience?

I use the telephone to work so I would like to properly understand the compatibility issues I am going to face if I decide to buy this telephone.

Best regards
Fran

EDIT: As per "smiley 1962" comments it seems like the whatsapp version is not working any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BQ Aquaris E 4.5 Ubuntu edition is a phone for early adopters: developers, enthusiasts, …

That being said, I use it for work as well (dual SIM: one private, one for work) and it phones, SMSes, can add contacts, can read my mail, navigate, allow me to to read books, listen to podcasts, watch videos etc.

If you want a collection of Ubuntu Touch apps being developed, look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Collection) and know that every day new apps get added to the Touch Store …

For your *very specific* use case, there is only one answer: Buy it, try it and if you don't like it, you *can downgrade* the firmware to Android!

***(Shudder…)***

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: *can downgrade the firmware to Android!* – **:P**

Comment: Actually, I looked into this and I am not sure you can downgrade. The Android version comes with two hardware keys not available on the Ubuntu version.

Comment: @wobbily_col: have you tried contacting BQ support on this and did they tell you they won't provide you the keys?

Comment: No, I didn't investigate too hard, just what I was reading in other forums.  All the Android phones I have owned had physical keys, so I assumed it was necessary.

Comment: @wobbily_col: NAAA (Never Assume, Always Ask)  I haven't asked neither though...  **;-)**  But my interaction with BQ support has been wonderful until now.

Comment: Long time since the last time I accessed my account here, so maybe you already know what I'm going to say: I installed Android in the mobile phone after asking these questions (long ago). As you point out @wobbily_col these keys are not visible. As soon as you know where each key is located it's not a big deal to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As for the whatsapp url you posted, thats a negative, tried it but the packages are no longer supported. There is no whatsapp for ubuntu touch.

Google drive has a good mobile website, so it will be easy to go there.

Comment: I was checking the whatsapp thing right now (i purchased the mobile phone two days ago) so, thanks for saving me that time!

Regarding drive it is difficult to manage two google accounts at the same time but you can do it by using the "app" and a webbrowser.

Many things started to work better after installing a Ubuntu Phone update.

Answer (score 0):

I have a BQ Aquaris E 4.5 Ubuntu edition but have to admit I have an Android phone as well (Motorola Moto G).  I need that for things like my banking app and navigation using Google Maps because the GPS is not good on the Ubuntu phone. Despite its limitations, however, I use my Ubuntu phone far more than my Android phone for things like Facebook (but it doesn't do their new chat) and email and reading news on the BBC website.